# How to make cdk virtual scroll itemSize auto or change by condition

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTuBX.png)

I have this piece of code in .html file that just loops through formArray controls and displays a component. The length of formArray is by default one, and can increase or decrease over time. I want the item size to be changeable or auto. Please help me to find a way to do that.